# Matlab join array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

In ruby and other languages, I can create an array, push an arbitrary number of strings and then join the array:

```
ary=[]

...
ary.push some_str
ary.push some_other_str
...

result = ary.join ""
```

How do I accomplish this in matlab?

**User story:** my plot legend is composed of a variable number of strings. The number of strings is determined runtime, so I want to declare the array, add strings dynamically and then join the array to the legend string in the end of the script.

Comment: `strcat`, `strjoin`?

Comment: Can you show an example that creates the array, pushes the strings and then joins? I am quite early in the learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, String joining happens like the following

```
a = 'ding';
b = 'dong';

c = [a ' ' b]; % Produces 'ding dong'
```

P.S. a `typeof(c,'char')` shows TRUE in MATLAB because it "joins" all characters into C.

Suppose you want to start with an empty `char` placeholder. You can do this.

a = ``; % Produces an empty character with 0x0 size.

Then you can keep adding to the end of it; like this:

`a = [a 'newly added'] % produces a = "newly added"`

To prove that it works, do this again:

`a = [a ' appended more to the end.'] % produces a = "newly added appended more to the end."`

You can always use the `end` keyword that points to the last index of an array, but in this case you need to append to `end+X` where `X` is the extra number of characters you are appending (annoyingly). I suggest you just use the [] operator to join/append.

There is also this `strjoin(C, delim)` function which joins a cell `C` of strings using a `delim` delimiter (could be whitespace or whatever). But cheap and dirty one is the one I showed above.

Comment: Thanks - seems to be the way. How do I push strings to the array before joining? Reason for asking is that the array will grow dynamically before being joined.

Comment: 'How do I push strings to the array before joining'...I am not quite clear what you mean. could you kindly update the question with a user story so that we understand the problem?

Comment: By pushing, I mean append - add to the end of the array.

Comment: @ChristianMadsen `c = [c 'new string'];` ? Or, if you want space in between, `c = [c ' ' 'new string'];`